# How to trap exit (ctrl+c) signal in Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, build, signals, gnu-make

I'm trying to **trap** exit (ctrl+c) signal to perform some cleanup activity .

In shell script i followed bellow function to trap,

```
#To trap ctrl-c signals
trap ctrl_c INT

#To trap exit signals
trap on_exit EXIT

function ctrl_c() {
    echo "exited by user"
    exit
}

function on_exit() {
    echo "exited by user"
    exit
}
```

How do I achieve same in Makefile ?

Comment: There is no way to do that in makefiles.  You can read about https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Interrupts.html and also https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#index-_002eDELETE_005fON_005fERROR but that's it.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. One could cleanup partially written object files when OOM kills occur. That would avoid linking problems later.

Answer (score 4):

You can't trap signals in make. Try using [`.INTERMEDIATE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) for cleanup and read [5.6 Interrupting or Killing make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Interrupts.html)

```
all: test.out

test.out: test.tmp
    sleep 10

test.tmp:
    echo x>test.tmp

.PHONY: all

.INTERMEDIATE: test.tmp
```

Make catches the interrupt signal and removes such files if they're part of the graph and didn't exist before launching:

```
$ make
echo x>test.tmp
sleep 10
make: *** [Makefile:4: test.out] Interrupt
make: *** Deleting intermediate file 'test.tmp'
```

If you really-really need to execute some program when make exits, spawn a background process in an initialization of some variable and let it wait for the main make process to terminate:

```
DUMMY := $(info launching the moniror process...)$(shell some-command& )
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to invoke a bash interpreter explicitly and define a trap there:

```
test.out:
    bash -c "trap 'rm test.tmp' EXIT; \
             echo x>test.tmp; \
             cp test.tmp test.out"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following at the beginning of a makefile:

```
ifdef MAKELEVEL
    ifeq "${MAKELEVEL}" "0"
        export SD:=$(shell mktemp -d ./.make-tmp_XXXXXXXX)
        $(info Launching clean up task for ${SD})
        $(shell { trap 'rm -rf ${SD};' EXIT; tail --pid=$$PPID -f /dev/null; }\
              </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &)
  endif
endif
```

First check if the make level is zero, so the running make is not a sub-make.  (This might be specific for my use case, where the submakes are supposed to use this directory and the files therein.)

If that is the case use `mktemp` to make a temporary directory and save the filename in the make-variable SD.

Then start a shell in the background that waits until its parent with PID $PPID exits.  The parent is the make-process, so this waits until the main make process is done.  The shell has an 'exit-trap' which deletes the temporary directory once it exits.  This works for regular exits of the make process or interrupting it with ctrl-c.

The hack with `tail` is special feature of `tail`, maybe only on linux.  From the man-page: "--pid=PID...  terminate after process ID, PID dies".  The bash builtin `wait` does not work, as it only waits for children...

Background:

I use files to communicate some information from sub-makes to the main make.  When the main make exits all this information is removed by removing the temporary directory.  Note, in my case the sub-makes use the same makefile.

Hope that helps.